# How to kill threads waiting more than a minute or 2 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to c++ and have some knowledge of c++ multi threading.
I have initially 10 threads and I am increasing number of threads on basis on number of tasks added to the multi map. I am able to increase thread count but not able to kill the threads if tasks are decreased in number. I will like to  kill threads which are waiting for more than 2 min and decrease number of threads according to tasks.
Can anyone help me on this ??.
Please bear with me as I am new to c++ and if this question is already asked.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't create new and kill old threads. That's expensive. Use a threadpool.

Comment: Are you implementing a thread pool? If so, you should take a look at exsisting implementations (and probably still write your own). In short, there's no way to cancel thread in the middle of execution (that would lead to unpredictable results because you can't tell where exactly it stops).

Comment: Also, thread just dies when its function exits (don't forget to join or detach it).

Comment: Design your code so that you don't need to kill a thread. If you need to ensure that your system is healthy, then have a thread that do some check at regular interval (say 30 seconds) and somehow warn you if unexpected delays are detected so that you can investigate the problem.

Comment: @Fureeish I have implemented threadpool initially of size 10, but I want it to expand and contract on tasks count. One thread will be  in loop always to check if there is any task in multimap, if there is any task it will be executed and removed. Can I achieve this and if yes how ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a "job of death". When your manager wants to shrink the size of the pool, it simply queues a "job of death". When a thread gets a job, it checks if it's a "job of death" and, if so, terminates itself cleanly.

You can do the same thing by having both an active thread count and a desired thread count protected by the same mutex that protects the job queue. To kill a thread, decrement the desired thread count and wake at least one thread. When a thread wakes up, before doing a job, check if the actual thread count is higher than desired and, if so, decrement the actual thread count and terminate the thread.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions possible:

- *Exiting*. Your threads are probably waiting for work on a queue/mutex. Details depend on the framework, but you can usually set a timeout on this wait operation. When the timeout is reached, the thread can simply return (terminate itself). Generally, you don't kill threads unless they are doing something bad.
- *Thread-Pool.* If the work done by your threads is CPU-bound, you should use a fixed number of threads. If you have more threads than CPU cores doing the same kind of work they just get into each other's way. Use a fixed thread-pool instead, and let unused threads wait on their queue - sleeping threads don't cost you much.
- *Event-Based.* If the work done by your threads is I/O bound, consider using an even-loop framework instead. Threading, and especially inter-thread synchronization, is very tricky to get right. Race-conditions and dead-locks are hard to debug, so the possibility of shared memory access should be avoided if you can. You don't need threads for most I/O bound operations. You can wait for multiple responses of different web servers in parallel with an event loop. Frameworks supporting this approach are e.g. asio and Qt.